# PHP Search Result Concatenation

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find a method in php to concat all related search return results from mysql DB into a single string separated by a comma. See below for DB table php output formats and php code.

Beach table:

```
bname    length  city_name
Beach A  4       City Z
Beach B  3       City X
Beach C  7       City E
```

Beach_Act_Type table:

```
bname        act_type
Beach A      Swimming
Beach A      Surfing
Beach B      Surfing
Beach C      Swimming
Beach C      Fishing
Beach C      Surfing
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
`beach`.`bname`    `beach_act_type`.`act_type`  
 Beach C           Swimming, Fishing, Surfing
```

Instead of this output format:

```
`beach`.`bname`    `beach_act_type`.`act_type`  
 Beach C           Swimming 
 Beach C           Fishing  
 Beach C           Surfing
```

My php code:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','test','','beachproject');

if (!$conn) {
    die('DB Connection Error');
}

$search = $_POST['search'];
$search_sql="select `beach`.`bname`, `beach_act_type`.`act_type` 
from `beach` inner join `beach_act_types` 
on `beach`.`bname`=`beach_act_type`.`bname` 
where `beach`.`bname`='$search'";
$search_query=$conn->query($search_sql);

if ($search_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $search_query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='4'>
        <tr>
        <th>Beach Name</th>
        <th>Beach Activity Allowed</th>
        </tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['bname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['act_type'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No Search Results";
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT 
    `beach`.`bname`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`beach_act_types`.`act_type`) types
FROM
    `beach`
INNER JOIN
    `beach_act_types` ON
        `beach`.`bname` = `beach_act_types`.`bname`
WHERE
    `beach`.`bname` = '$search'
```

> PS. You should be warned that you have SQL injection present, consider switching to prepared statements instead.

Answer (score -2):

You are just crrating two seperate table data which wont give you result you want , try the code below
You cant get "," in different table data.
Try this ,

```
    <?php $conn = new
  mysqli('localhost','test','','beachproject');
  if (!$conn) { die('DB Connection
  Error'); }
  $search = $_POST['search'];
  $search_sql="select `beach`.`bname`,
 `beach_act_type`.`act_type` from
 `beach` inner join `beach_act_types` on
 `beach`.`bname`=`beach_act_type`.`
  bname` where
  `beach`.`bname`='$search'";
 $search_query=$conn
 >query($search_sql); 
 if ($search_query->num_rows > 0) { 
 while($row = $search_query
 >fetch_assoc()) { echo "<table
 border='1' cellpadding='4'>
 <tr> <th>Beach Name</th> <th>Beach
 Activity Allowed</th> </tr>"; echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['bname'] . , .
 $row['act_type']"</td>"; echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>"; } } else { echo "No
 Search Results"; } ?>
```

Comment: is your enter key broke?

Comment: @nogad Yes my enter key is broke manage to copy and add yourself

Comment: this answer is irrelevant

Comment: @AliveColdJuan with an attitude like that you won't move up. Your answer is unreadable, so no one is going to give it the time of day.

Comment: @AliveColdJuan first : learn how to write readable code, second : try to actually read and understand the question, and then work on your attitude, and take a look at the next answer and try to learn something from it :)

Comment: do you use an IDE to write code? most will auto-format for you.

Comment: @nogad even without an IDE this is a simple code to format :)

Comment: Does the suggested format repeat more than one 'act_type' if the beach_act_type table has more than one listing for that beach? For example, Beach C has 3 different types of activities 'swimming', 'surfing', 'fishing'. I'm looking to echo out all three activities separated by a comma in 1 entry if possible instead of the echo creating 3 different entries because of the three different activity types.

Comment: For that you can try to insert all types of beaches in one column